# How can I explain these linear regression charts well on my scientific poster?

Tags: regression, self-study, data-visualization, interpretation

I know that these laboratory analysis reports each have a linear regression relationship and two have a positive slope and one has a negative slope. I am taking my first statistics class and want to be able to explain these very well in a research poster I am doing for work. Am I missing any important information? The negative slope indicates that the values are decreasing together negatively. The positive means they are increasing together. The ADL concentration chart does not have a very good relation but there is still a relation.
[image: ADL linear regression]

[image: ADF linear regression]
[image: r^2, p-value]

[image: NDF linear regression]

Comment: I would add the regression line to them.

Comment: "*The negative slope indicates that the values are decreasing together negatively*".  If they 'decrease together' (i.e. one decreases when the other one decreases) they'd have a *positive slope*. You mean that one *decreases* as the other *increases*, which is the opposite of any sense of 'together'. Adding 'negatively' to the end of that doesn't serve to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the regression line that Jeremy suggested, it would be helpful to your audience to have the p-value of the slope and the R-squared. I'm not sure *how* new you are to this, but you can the p-value of the slope is really part of a test of whether or not the slope = 0. If the p-value is statistically significant (p < 0.05 usually) then you can be pretty confident that the slope is not zero and that there is likely to be a "real" relationship between the independent and dependent variables. The R-squared shows how much of the variation in y is explained by variation in x. For instance, I would suspect that the ADL relationship is probably real (significant p-value) but that the R-squared will be low-ish. This isn't bad, but simply means that there are probably other things affecting ADL sorghum silage aside from ADL fresh sorghum.

Comment: When working w/ novices, it's helpful to keep explanations simpler even if you sacrifice a little nuance & accuracy; however, describing what p-values are as telling "you if there is actually a relationship between the independent and dependent variables" may be a bit too far in that direction for comfort.

Comment: I appreciate the comment gung. I haven't ever answered a question before on here before. I only ventured to help on this one as I have taught simple linear regression to about 150 biology students in the last year but perhaps I've gotten too used to toning it down. I'll see if there's a way to delete answers.

Comment: What is the difference between the r^2 value and the adjusted r^2 value? Also if you look at the blue chart on the bottom this includes a p-value and adjusted r^2